# ValueError: [!] Model file not found in the output path

Tags: python, text-to-speech

When I configured a visual interface of a face-talking video generation model in a conda virtual environment on a linux server, the TTS module reported an error message. I tried to use pip install TTS to update a version, but it still didn’t solve the problem. I don’t know Any idea how to reinstall this mod or, what should I do please

```
File "launcher.py", line 204, in <module>
   start()
File "launcher.py", line 198, in start
   demo = sadtalker_demo()
File "/home/jiahuaw/test/SadTalker/SadTalker/app_sadtalker.py", line 49, in sadtalker_demo
   tts_talker = TTSTalker()
File "/home/jiahuaw/test/SadTalker/SadTalker/src/utils/text2speech.py", line 9, in __init__
   self.tts = TTS(model_name)
File "/home/jiahuaw/test/SadTalker/SadTalker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TTS/api.py", line 289, in __init__
   self.load_tts_model_by_name(model_name, gpu)
File "/home/jiahuaw/test/SadTalker/SadTalker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TTS/api.py", line 385, in load_tts_model_by_name
   model_path, config_path, vocoder_path, vocoder_config_path, model_dir = self.download_model_by_name(
File "/home/jiahuaw/test/SadTalker/SadTalker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TTS/api.py", line 348, in download_model_by_name
   model_path, config_path, model_item = self.manager.download_model(model_name)
File "/home/jiahuaw/test/SadTalker/SadTalker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TTS/utils/manage.py", line 309, in download_model
   output_model_path, output_config_path = self._find_files(output_path)
File "/home/jiahuaw/test/SadTalker/SadTalker/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/TTS/utils/manage.py", line 332, in _find_files
   raise ValueError(" [!] Model file not found in the output path")
 ValueError:  [!] Model file not found in the output path
```

Comment: The error is not a install error. The package requires a model, and it isn't where the package expect it to be

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

```py
self.tts = TTS(model_name)
```

`model_name` should be a model file path in your local file system.